# Ampersand problem in an xml file using shell script

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I have an xml file which contains below

```
<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName>
<jobs>
<job>
```

where, Licensed Original,  , Licensed Reversal are static

I want output like below

```
<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original PCI & Liability Waiver</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal PCI & Liability Waiver</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original PCI & Liability Waiver</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal PCI & Liability Waiver</eName>
<jobs>
<job>
```

But when i am running my code i am getting below output

```
<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original PCI <eName>Licensed Original MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName> Liability Waiver</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal PCI <eName>Licensed Reversal MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName> Liability Waiver</eName>
<jobs>
<job>
<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Original PCI <eName>Licensed Original MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName> Liability Waiver</eName>
<jobs>
<job>

<SummaryRecordMapping>
<eName>Licensed Reversal PCI <eName>Licensed Reversal MC TPE EXCESSIVE AUTH</eName> Liability Waiver</eName>
<jobs>
<job>
```

Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    NAME="`echo "$line" | awk '{$1=""; print}'`"
    sed "s#^<eName>Licensed Original.*</eName>#<eName>Licensed Original$NAME</eName>#;s#^<eName>Licensed Reversal.*</eName>#<eName>Licensed Reversal$NAME</eName>#" LO.xml >> LR.xml
done < input.txt
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: you want to dupplicate field in a (valid ?) xml file, `grep`,`awk` and `sed` are poor choice in this case. Have you consider `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint` ?

Answer (score 3):

In `sed` substitutions, the ampersand represents the matched text that is being replaced.

You will need to escape the ampersand with a backslash to insert a literal ampersand: `\&`

Apart from this issue, note that you should use an entity to represent an ampersand in XML anyway: use `&amp;` to represent a plain ampersand character.

Putting these together means the you need to use `\&amp;` in you `sed` replacement text to insert a plain ampersand.

EDIT:

Change the `NAME=` line in your code to:

```
NAME="`echo "$line" | awk '{$1=""; print}' | sed 's/&/\\\\&amp;/g'`"
```

The backslash needs to be inserted twice, once to escape it from `sed`, and once from the shell in the `NAME=` assignment.

That should do what you want it to do.

Note that as Archemar commented, manipulating XML with `sed` etc. can be tricky unless you are sure the input won't change format, there aren't any less than `<` or greater than `>` symbols in the input, etc.

Comment: used sed -e 's/\&\([^\amp;]\)/\&amp;\1/' command but still the issue is persistant

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: Thanks it worked